# Setting top and bottom spacing for a BarChart - iOS Charts

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am trying to give my chart some top and bottom spacing, so it won't appear as on the picture below.

[image: in]

Is there any way to set either maximum height or add a padding, so the label(in this case -1) won't collide with the date?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Try ChartView.extraBottomOffset = 40

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such offset available yet, take a look at `internal func drawLabels`, this is how it calculates the position. You can change yourself for now. But I think it's more like a bug, which happens with negative values, I filed a bug on github https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/issues/481.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to change the spacing between the bottom of the bar chart and the label with `chartView.xAxis.yOffset = 10`